# string indices must be integers - Spark UDF or Pands UDF with a Large Language Model in Databricks

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, databricks

I have a pandas dataframe from a csv file and I want to process it with Mistral, which is a model from the databricks catalog.

Functions are like this:

```
import mlflow
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql import Window
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
from typing import Iterator

# Global variable to store the loaded model
mlflow.set_registry_uri("databricks-uc")

loaded_model = None

def setup_spark_session(app_name, executor_instances=None, executor_cores=None, executor_memory=None):
    """
    Set up a Spark session with specified configurations.

    Parameters:
        app_name (str): Name of the Spark application.
        executor_instances (int): Number of executor instances.
        executor_cores (int): Number of executor cores.
        executor_memory (str): Executor memory.

    Returns:
        SparkSession: Configured Spark session.
    """
    spark = (
        SparkSession.builder
            .appName(app_name)
            .config("spark.executor.instances", str(executor_instances))
            .config("spark.executor.cores", str(executor_cores))
            .config("spark.executor.memory", executor_memory)
            .getOrCreate()
    )

    # Display default and updated configuration values
    display_spark_configuration(spark)

    return spark

def display_spark_configuration(spark):
    """
    Display Spark configuration values.

    Parameters:
        spark (SparkSession): Spark session.
    """
    print("Spark Configuration:")
    print(f"   spark.executor.instances: {spark.conf.get('spark.executor.instances')}")
    print(f"   spark.executor.cores: {spark.conf.get('spark.executor.cores')}")
    print(f"   spark.executor.memory: {spark.conf.get('spark.executor.memory')}")

def load_mlflow_model(catalog_name, model_name, version):
    global loaded_model

    if loaded_model is None:
        logged_model = f"models:/{catalog_name}.models.{model_name}/{version}"
        loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, logged_model, "string")


# Modify the load_mlflow_model_as_pandas_udf function to return an Iterator Pandas UDF
def load_mlflow_model_as_grouped_map_udf(spark, df, catalog_name, model_name, version):
    load_mlflow_model(catalog_name, model_name, version)  # Load the model once

    @pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def apply_model_to_batch(key, iterator):
        results = []
        for pdf in iterator:
            pdf['mistralresponse'] = loaded_model(pdf['NewBody'])
            results.append(pdf)
        return pd.concat(results)

    return apply_model_to_batch

def read_csv_into_dataframe(spark, csv_path):
    """
    Read a CSV file into a Spark DataFrame.

    Parameters:
        spark (SparkSession): Spark session.
        csv_path (str): Path to the CSV file.

    Returns:
        DataFrame: Spark DataFrame containing CSV data.
    """
    start_time = datetime.now()
    df = spark.read.csv(csv_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)
    end_time = datetime.now()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    print(f"CSV file read into DataFrame in {duration}")
    return df

def add_additional_text_column(df, additional_text):
    """
    Add a new column with additional text to an existing DataFrame.

    Parameters:
        df (DataFrame): Input DataFrame.
        additional_text (str): Additional text to append to the column.

    Returns:
        DataFrame: DataFrame with an additional text column.
    """
    return df.withColumn("NewBody", concat(lit(additional_text), df["Body"]))

def test_udf_performance(spark, model_name, catalog_name, version, csv_path, additional_text, max_records=50):
    # Read CSV into DataFrame
    df = read_csv_into_dataframe(spark, csv_path)

    # Limit the number of records for testing
    df = df.limit(max_records)

    # Concatenate additional text to the "Body" column
    df = add_additional_text_column(df, additional_text)

    # Generate a unique BatchId for each partition
    window_spec = Window().orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    df = df.withColumn("BatchId", F.row_number().over(window_spec))

    # Cache the DataFrame for better performance
    df.cache()

    # Get the schema of the batch DataFrame
    batch_df_schema = df.schema

    # Load MLflow model as a pandas UDF
    udf = load_mlflow_model_as_grouped_map_udf(spark, df, catalog_name, model_name, version)

    # Apply the pandas UDF to the DataFrame
    result_df = df.groupby('BatchId').apply(udf)

    # Write the results to a CSV file
    #output_path = f'file:/Workspace/Users/user/.ide/results.csv'
    #result_df.write.mode("overwrite").csv(output_path)

    return result_df
```

and I eecute it like this:

```
import os
os.environ["MLFLOW_ENABLE_ARTIFACTS_PROGRESS_BAR"] = "false"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_name = "MistralApp"
    setup_spark_session(app_name, executor_instances=2, executor_cores=2, executor_memory="4")

    model_name = "mistral_7b_instruct_v0_1"
    version = "1"
    catalog_name = "databricks_mistral_models"
    csv_path = "file:/Workspace/Users/user/.ide/BigDataParallelAPIProcessing-0fc9a8d0/processed_data.csv"
    additional_text = "You are a helpful assistant which only task is to analyze the text of emails sent to a customer service mailbox.  From this text you must extract a category.  No category labels will be provided. Email: "

    result_df = test_udf_performance(
        spark, model_name, catalog_name, version, csv_path, additional_text, max_records=1
    )
```

My compute size is Standard_NC24s_v3
which is 448gb of memory and 4GPUS

However I get this warning:

```
To fix the mismatches, call `mlflow.pyfunc.get_model_dependencies(model_uri)` to fetch the model's environment and install dependencies using the resulting environment file.
2024/02/13 08:29:51 WARNING mlflow.pyfunc: Calling `spark_udf()` with `env_manager="local"` does not recreate the same environment that was used during training, which may lead to errors or inaccurate predictions. We recommend specifying `env_manager="conda"`, which automatically recreates the environment that was used to train the model and performs inference in the recreated environment.
2024/02/13 08:29:51 INFO mlflow.models.flavor_backend_registry: Selected backend for flavor 'python_function'
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/group_ops.py:104: UserWarning: It is preferred to use 'applyInPandas' over this API. This API will be deprecated in the future releases. See SPARK-28264 for more details.
```

If I try:

```
display(result_df)
```

then I get:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 11) (10.139.64.4 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<command-4040453931768083>", line 72, in apply_model_to_batch
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```